# Why I am not getting signal SIGKILL on kill -9 command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, signals

In bash script I handle different signal as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sighdl () 
{
  echo "signal caught"
  #do something
  exit 0
}

trap sighdl SIGKILL SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Above code handle signal properly for following activity:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. `kill pid`
3. `pkill scriptname`

For `kill -9 pid` it does not call `sighdl`. As per my understanding (if I am not wrong) `kill -9` sends the SIGKILL signal.

Any idea?

Comment: From the man `-9 KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)` does this means it'll not call `sighdl` ?

Comment: Sig kill cannot be caught... There are two signals that can't be caught SIGKILL and SIGSTOP

Comment: @Q_SaD..Any way to notify my script on `kill -9` command?

Comment: SIGKILL isn't really a signal, in that you aren't requesting an action from the process in response. It is simply a request to the OS to dispose of the process, no questions asked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot do that. Yes 9 is `SIGKILL` and Unix system by design doesn't allow any script/program to trap `SIGKILL` due to security reasons. Otherwise any script can trap & ignore SIGKILL which will make impossible to terminate that script by OS.

Comment: ok..can i attach user defined signal with `kill -9`? Because i need to notify script when user kill the script process by any way.

Comment: You cannot notify when user sends `kill -9`. Any other signal you can catch and handle.

Comment: @Jayesh Simply put, it is the *user's* fault, not the script's, if the script cannot clean up after itself properly after the user sends `SIGKILL`. Think of it this way: the OS can't shutdown properly if you were to unplug the computer (or pull the battery), and `SIGKILL` is the software equivalent of pulling the plug on a process.

Comment: but why is `trap blabla kill` valid syntax then?

Comment: Question was about handling signal `9`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can trap SIGKILL in SunOS (Solaris), but not in Linux (validated in Red Hat).

In Linux you can kill the foreign process softly with

```
kill -15 $PID
```

Comment: It's worth noting, that 15 is `SIGTERM` - the default signal for `kill`. You can therefore omit the signal from the above command.