# Java Process Termination - onEnd()?

Tags: java, linux, unix, process, pid

When you force kill a process by PID:

```
kill -9 1123
```

Is there any method that is called when the process is terminated, that halts until shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For java, you can add a ShutdownHook to your process, when `sigterm` is send to this process, the code in ShutdownHook will be executed before jvm shuts itself down.

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your cleanup codes
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the links to check the difference between both signals and how to trap them, etc.

In a nutshell, `sigterm` allows the process to clean his stuff (his last will) before the end but `sigkill` does not and can not be trapped by your application! (imagine programs running forever and unstoppable this would be a mess)

**Additional readings:**

[Why I am not getting signal SIGKILL on kill -9 command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807714/why-i-am-not-getting-signal-sigkill-on-kill-9-command-in-bash)

https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

http://www.learnlinux.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch12s03.html

Comment: Thank you! I will post my results :)